# Heroku Free Tier - Can a single app spend all Dyno quota?

Tags: heroku, free, quota, dyno

If I only have one active app is it possible that it could spend all free Dyno hours quota?

My app is a PHP process which is always active (while (true) { do_something}). I launch this process as a worker.

I thought the free Dyno hours quota were like real hours so you can spent 24h as max per day. But if I view my remaining free hours quota in two consecutive days using 'heroku ps -a app' command then I get that I am spending more than 24h per day.

Another question, how many hours do you have in a Hobby plan?

Comment: I think this would be more suited to be asked to Heroku support team

Comment: How many replicas of this worker role do you have?

Comment: I only have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running 2 dynos (for example, a web dyno and a worker dyno), they will each use 24 hours, for a total of 48 dyno hours used in a day. Of course in reality it would probably be less than 24 hours each, if the dynos slept for part of the day.

I solved my problem disabling the web Dyno.